# Pyinstaller ImportError: cannot import name 'dist' on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, importerror

I am trying to build a Python (version 3.6) project on Windows (version 8.1) using Pyinstaller (version 3.3) into single exe-file. The project includes PyQt5, numpy, matplotlib dependencies. Pyinstaller writes:

```
Building EXE from out00-exe.toc completed successfully.
```

But when I run the exe-file, I get:

```
...
  File "distutils\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
[6748] Failed to execute script myproj
```

The file `"distutils\__init__.py"` at line 44 contains the import:

```
from distutils import dist, sysconfig  # isort:skip
```

This project can be built on Ubuntu without troubles and works fine. I have tried to add hidden imports:

```
'distutils',
'distutils.dist',
'dist',
```

It didn't help.

Why did this error come on Windows exactly and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when trying to build a Django project (not PyQT) on Windows 7 64bit. I used `PyInstaller 3.4`.

In my case the issue went away by downgrading to `Python 3.5` (I created a new anaconda environment with the other Python version), then it started working.

I don't know if it will work for you, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I have tried it carefully, it didn't work for me though... I got the same error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Any new insights here?  @Ralf, which Python version did you exactly use? I tried 3.5.4 but got the same error